# FuzzyLogic in Mathematica

Tags: packages, logic

Just a question for my information.
What package do I need to load or to buy to be able to use fuzzy logic in *Mathematica*?

I tried

```
<< FuzzyLogic
```

but obviously failed.

Thanks.

Comment: I noted [this package](http://reference.wolfram.com/applications/fuzzylogic/), but I do not know whether it is still available and concurrent.

Comment: thank you.and if somebody has more informatiion i am happy about to read :)